# Is this christian rendering of the Temple accurate?

Tags: beis-hamikdash

This 3D virtual-reality animation, does it look accurate according to Jewish sources?

Screenshot: [image: https://i.imgur.com/QdE8NJA.jpg]

Additional screenshots: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHPQa.jpg

Source video: https://youtu.be/EHs07DVRzOs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Christians don't have a tradition of their own so any rendering would be based on the Jewish tradition.

The Temple is a very complicated structure with lots of detail, it's not just a nice building. The outside looks pretty much standard, and the dimensions look proportional.

As far as I could see the short movie it seemed authentic. If you have any questions about the details please specify.

Comment: They don’t have a tradition? What about I Kings and other Old Testament sources?

Comment: Since when are these Christian texts? Or did you mean to write they are accepting the Jewish tradition